# Running services with keyboard shortcuts has a 0.5 second delay

Tags: keyboard, automator, shortcut

I've created app launchers for certain apps in `Automator` and assigned keyboard shortcuts from the Keyboard Preferences menu.

When I use these shortcuts I get a 1/2 a second delay. 
It seems like it's using the menu `Services` sub-menu to run the script and that seems to cause the delay.

Is there any way to circumvent this and run it immediately?

Thanks.

Comment: I also have this problem. Not sure if the delay is a menu issue, maybe it is taking some time to load the scrip from the HD.