# Automator services run with 0.5 second delay

Tags: macos, automator

There is a 0.5 second delay between triggering a service (via the Services menu or a shortcut) and the service actually performing the actions. For some workflows that I run via a shortcut, this delay is pretty annoying.

Is there a way to get my AppleScript and shell scripts executed (almost) instantly via a shortcut?

This question has been asked before but it has no answers: [Running services with keyboard shortcuts has a 0.5 second delay](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339364/running-services-with-keyboard-shortcuts-has-a-0-5-second-delay)

**Update**: [My solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385348/247390).

Comment: I **had** been using Keyboard Maestro to do this.  Seemed like applescript ran immediately, but with an upgrade to keyboard maestro I get an annoying message asking if I want to run the macro. I'll see if I can get around this message some how and post back, but no idea when.  You can try out maestro for free. I'm on 10.10.5. with later versions of macos, your going to have to get past macos security.  There are other keyboard apps. I'm thinking about try maestro > bash > applescript to avoid the message

Comment: @historystamp I decided to give FastScripts a shot and really like it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I decided to give [FastScripts](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) a shot, since I've heard [positive things](https://daringfireball.net/2020/01/quit_confirmation_for_safari_on_macos) about it in the past. Guess what? Scripts run *instantly* now. It's a wonderful app all-around. If you're even slightly bothered by the delays I'd highly recommend it. Keyboard Maestro is probably great as well but FastScripts seemed more like the light-weight app that I was looking for.

Comment: Keyboard maestro is a little bloated and has a learning curve. While macos' keyboard short cuts have been enhanced over the years, I've not had any success with them. I guess they do something.